# Advertisement vs Publicity

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I've recently come across the two sentences below:

> Lee is getting a lot of advertisement at the fashion show.

and

> The designer of Mai's dress will get a lot of good advertisement.

Are the two sentences correct? I'm specifically referring to the person's use of the word *advertisement*, where *publicity* might be more suitable.

Comment: We can never know without any context. Context, please. Also, include some research you've done before asking this question and state why you think there is something wrong with the sentences. Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony I didn't think my post needed much context, but here it is: Lee is a designer and Mai is a celebrity. I came across those two sentences on twitter and they are both from the same user. The two sentences struck me as odd which is why I asked the question here.

Comment: The issue is I don't understand your question. What is your question?

Comment: @Rathony I think the question is actually hinted at in the title. I'll add that to the body. However, goo, you need to demonstrate your own research into the words *advertisement* and *publicity* (which might be rendered moot by the answer already here, but you must present your own research in future questions, which should be clearly asked in the body of the question regardless of their headline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Neither sentence is correct. The correct word is getting a lot of "publicity". "lee is getting a lot of publicity at the show".  An advertisement is a noun meaning the support for the publicity, for example a newspaper or TV advertisement is published to give publicity for a product.  To advertise, the verb, is to publish information that provides "publicity".